# Web API In Memory Integration Testing - Authentication between two services

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, integration-testing, owin, in-memory

I have searched lots of posts here regarding my problem but have not found anything related to what I am trying to achieve.

I have created a Web API micro service for handling user authentication.  The service uses identity framework and issues bearer tokens.  I have another Web API which is secured using the [Authroize] attribute on the controllers.  Both services talk to the same database via Entity Framework.

One hurdle I had to overcome whilst setting up this infrastructure was both services require the same machine key in their web.configs.  When everything is deployed it works great.

However, I am trying to write some integration tests for my main API using the Microsoft Owin TestServer.  This allows me to write integration tests against an in memory copy of the API which also uses an in memory copy of the database using the entity framework migrations.

I have successfully created integration tests for my user service.  However, I am struggling to get integration tests working for my main service.  I have created a solution with a new test project in it.  I have also linked in my user service and main service.  In the bootstrap for the integration tests, I spin up an in memory copy of each service by using each services Startup.cs.

Everything works ok until I try to hit a controller that is secured with the [Authorize] attribute.  I have successfully hit the user service to register a user, activate that user and obtain the bearer token. I am then passing this over in the request to the main service in the auth header.  However, I always an Unauthorized response from the service.

I suspect this is related to machine keys again and have tried putting the same machine key into an App.config within the integration test project.  This did not make any difference.

If anyone has managed to get this scenario working I would very much appreciate any advice on what could be causing the problem.  I haven't pasted any code as there is quite a lot involved but would be happy to paste any specifics.

Testing in this way is super fast and really powerful.  However, there seems to be a lack of info out there on getting this working.

**EDIT**

Here is some code as requested.  The two in memory APIs are created in a OneTimeSetUp as follows:

```
_userApi = TestServer.Create<UserApi.Startup>();
_webApi = TestServer.Create<WebApi.Startup>();
```

The Authorized HttpClient is then taken from the API as follows:

```
var client = _webApi.HttpClient;
var authorizationValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authorizationValue;
```

"token" is obtained from the user service.

The GET is then performed using the client as follows:

```
var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

**EDIT 2**

I should also point out that I have authenticated integration tests working within the User Service.  The problem is only when I try to use both services together.  E.g.  Obtain token from User Service and use that token to authenticate against my main service.  The in memory entity framework database is created as follows:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, string.Empty));
using (new ContractManagerDatabase())
{
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ContractManagerDatabase>());
}
```

Comment: Put some code that you have tried.

Comment: I am literally going through the same thing. I am using the same setup, although I am using JWT and just getting Invalid Grant token error responses. What's weird is that it works locally but when I have the integration tests run on CI builds, they fail. Are yours working locally too?

Comment: Mine are not working locally either.  Everything seems to point to the machine key as until I put the same key in both configs I had the same problem when deployed onto IIS.  Its isolated to the tests in Visual Studio at the moment, haven't pushed to CI yet......sounds like I may be in for more fun with that too!  I will post some sample code as requested.

Comment: @py7133 - I had invalid grant errors when I wasn't using grant_type = password in the request.  Not sure if its the same with JWT.

Comment: Just from what you sent above, at least via using JWT, you would be using a POST request and not a GET request. What happens if you swap that?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  My call to the user service to get the token is a POST request.  I am then trying to test a method that is a HttpGet on a controller that is secured with the Authorize attribute.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. I misread. Actually I got my builds to start working. Are there other secret/signing keys involved that may need to be the same between the two servers?

Comment: Only machineKey that I am aware of.  How did you get yours working?  Do you have other keys?

Comment: Unfortunately my issue was a bit simpler than yours since I misread the part about you having two APIs that need to communicate with each other. I've only got one, and with me using JWT, I did have a secret + signing key that's set up with the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions and JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions - those worked without issue. Have you looked at this? http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I used that when initially setting up the architecture.  However, it does not go as far as integration testing with in-memory apis.

Comment: With the in-memory API, have you checked that both OWIN test servers both point to the same database context? I wonder that if your tokens are being accepted at the main API already and just not finding the user from the DB context that the main API was created with, that would probably return the unauthorized. When I resolved my issue, I had to update the code to ensure the ApplicationOAuthProviders were creating the context objects for the ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationRoleManager, and DB Context by the in-memory version of the DB Context instead of the original DB Context.

Comment: I initially thought that it may be spinning up two in memory databases; one for each service.  However, I can remove the authorize attribute and query the users in the database which reveals that the registered user is present.  I will check further into the ApplicationUserManager though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after days of battling with this I have finally found a solution.  The first thing I did was to move the integration tests back into the main Web API.  Having taken a step back and thinking more about the problem I realised that by creating a separate solution and spinning up my user service and Web API in memory all I was really testing was Identity Framework and not the API itself.

I have integration tests working just fine in my user service for both unauthenticated and authenticated calls.  It seemed to me that I should be able to do the same with the Web API and not rely on the user service.

I thought that I must be able to "bypass" the [Authorize] attribute to test the API.  After some google searching, I found the following article which was most valuable in getting the solution working:

https://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2016/03/10/asp-net-web-api-owin-authenticated-integration-tests-without-authorization-server/

The key things for me were as follows:

1. The http client needed to be constructed differently for the test.

   ```
   var client = new HttpClient(_webApp.Handler) {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost")};
   ```
2. The call to GET had to be constructed differently for the test.

   ```
   token = token == string.Empty ? GenerateToken(userName, userId) : token;
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
   var client = GetAuthenticatedClient(token);
   return await client.SendAsync(request);
   ```
3. The token needs to be generated as follows.  I also needed to add a claim for the User Id as this is taken from the request within the controller.

   ```
   private static string GenerateToken(string userName, int userId)
   {
       var claims = new[]
       {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()) 
       };
       var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");

       var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1) };
       var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
       var format = new TicketDataFormat(_dataProtector);
       var token = format.Protect(ticket);
       return token;
   }
   ```

I hope this post helps others with similar issues and thanks to everyone who contributed.